# Tweets ending with a sentence fragment. What happened?

Tags: writing-style, sentence-fragments, trumpism

I've been active on Twitter for many years, but recently something strange has been happening, and I don't mean suspicious, but something I can't explain, you see, people have been writing tweets and then ending them with fragments, something like "Sad!", or "No good!", and I'm thinking to myself, "Is this really happening, and why?" Anyone?

Is it becoming more common for tweets to end with a sentence fragment, and if so, was it a trend created by Donald Trump?

Comment: IMHO, this has always been the case. Twitter messages are short (<140 characters) and every character you can save, counts.

Comment: I don't think "Sad!" or "No good!" is a fragment.

Comment: I'm willing to accuse The Donald of many things, but this is just normal stuff that you are likely noticing more because you've changed who you follow.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. This is a good observation and a legitimate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sad!* is definitely a Twitter Trumpism:

> Failing [@NYTimes](https://twitter.com/nytimes) will always take a good story about me and make it bad. Every article is unfair and biased. Very sad!
>
> — Donald J. Trump (@realDonaldTrump) [May 20, 2016](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/733691591198703616)

and

> Wow, Lyin' Ted Cruz really went wacko today. Made all sorts of crazy charges. Can't function under pressure - not very presidential. Sad!
>
> — Donald J. Trump (@realDonaldTrump) [May 3, 2016](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/727634574298255361)

When people use this to punctuate an observation, they are mocking Trump's Twitter style:

> Job growth is sharply slowing at just the right time to help Trump win. Sad! https://t.co/FKSwlTfafU [pic.twitter.com/oaJIKc3buc](https://t.co/oaJIKc3buc)
>
> — Matthew Yglesias (@mattyglesias) [June 3, 2016](https://twitter.com/mattyglesias/status/738722050223837185)

and

> "Donald Trump doesn’t think his campaign needs anyone but Donald Trump. Sad!"
>   https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2016/06/06/donald-trump-doesnt-think-his-campaign-needs-anyone-but-donald-trump-sad/